# Populate 5 fragment pages with separate arraylists

Tags: android

I've been stuck for days on this. I have an activity that will parse html and sort the information into 5 arraylists. Each arraylist is a weekday. I want to take each arraylist and display the information in a listview on a separate page, so monday will be displayed on one page and then by swiping you move to tuesday and so on.

I have taken the eclipse default scrollable tabs + swipe for navigation and I'm trying to build from there.

So essentially I want to populate 5 pages of data with 5 arraylists, 1 arraylist for each page. Any ideas how I assign an arraylist to listview in a specific page?

Here is the code I have so far

```
public class DisplayOnlineTimetable extends FragmentActivity {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
String value;   
Document doc = null;
private ListView mainListView ;  

static ViewGroup mViewGroup;
ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_display_online_timetable_dummy);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_online_timetable, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return DummySectionFragment.newInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        //monday
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            //tuesday
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            //wednesday
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            //thursday
        case 3:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            //friday
        case 4:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public void createTimetable(ArrayList<SingleClass> list, Elements elements, Day day)
{

}   



private class CreateTimetables extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> 
{
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) 
    {

    }
}
```

}

DummySectionFragment Class

```
public class DummySectionFragment extends ListFragment {
private Integer arrayListId;
ViewGroup myViewGroup;
public static final String CATEGORY_POSITION = "section_number";
public static DummySectionFragment newInstance(int pos) {
    DummySectionFragment f = new DummySectionFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CATEGORY_POSITION, pos);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //get the id for your array list
    arrayListId = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(CATEGORY_POSITION) - 1 : 1;
}

//create the list view layout
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
myViewGroup = container;
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, container, false);
return v;
 }

//populate the list view row
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<SingleClass> arrayAdapter =      
 new ArrayAdapter<SingleClass>(getActivity(), android.R.id.list, R.layout.list_row);

    setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is standard, and you are almost there.

First in your ViewPager adapter's getItem methods, initiate the Fragment with which position it is on:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return DummySectionFragment.newInstance(i);
}
```

Next, in your Fragment class, create a constructor to instantiate it:

```
public static DummySectionFragment newInstance(int pos) {
    DummySectionFragment f = new DummySectionFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(CATEGORY_POSITION, pos);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

And now make your DummySectionFragment extend a ListFragment, and in the onActivityCreated method you  can populate it:

```
public class DummySectionFragment extends ListFragment {
    private Integer arrayListId;
    //the constructor from above

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //get the id for your array list
        arrayListId = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt(CATEGORY_POSITION) - 1 : 1;
    }

    //create the list view layout
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myViewGroup = container;
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
    return v;
}

    //populate the list view row
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.list, <your_array_list_row.xml>);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

The above code for your Fragment class will get the id for your array based on the position of the fragment, and create an ArrayAdapter for it, and use this adapter to populate a listview fragment. Now all you have to do is create the xml layout for the list:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

One last thing is make sure all your Fragment class are from the same set of library (eg. either the regular Fragment lib or support.v4).

Comment: Thank for the help. `@Override
  public Fragment getItem(int i) {
      return DummySectionFragment.newInstance(i);
  }` I'm getting an error here: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from DisplayOnlineTimetable.DummySectionFragment to Fragment"

Comment: Create your fragment as a separate class, not under your DisplayOnlineTimetable class

Comment: The code looks fine to me, you can simply cast it to @Override public Fragment getItem(int i) { return (Fragment) DummySectionFragment.newInstance(i); }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28609/discussion-between-wangyif2-and-user2236580)